# python code for inserting "N" in genome

Tags: python, fasta

I am having problem in my code I am trying to read a fasta file i.e. "chr1.fa", then I have a mutation file which looks like this

```
chr1    822979  822980  CLL6.08_1_snv   88.2    +
chr1    1052781 1052782 CLL6.08_2_snv   388.9   +
chr1    1216196 1216197 CLL6.08_3_snv   625 +
chr1    5053847 5053848 CLL6.08_4_snv   722.2   +
chr1    5735093 5735094 CLL6.08_5_snv   138.9   +
```

this is a tab delimited file with chr1 as first column and + as last. I want to insert a N in the chr1.fa file the using the location from the second column.My code looks like this

```
     #!/usr/bin/python
     # Filename: mutation.py
      import sys , os
      import numpy as np
      import re

    #declaring the variables
     lst = ''
     chr_name = ''
     first_cord = ''
     second_cord = ''
     lstFirstCord = []
     sequence = ''
     human_genome = ''
     seqList = ''

    # Method to read the Genome file (file contains data for only one chromosome)
     def ReadgenomeCharacter():
     header = ' '
     seq = ' '
  try:
      human_genome = raw_input("Enter UCSC fasta file of human genome:")
      human_seq = open(human_genome, 'rw+')
      line = human_seq.readline()
 except:
    print 'File cannot be opened, wrong format you forgot something:', human_genome
    exit()
 while line:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')   
    if '>' in line:           
        header = line
    else:
        seq = seq + line
    line = human_seq.readline()
print header
print "Length of the chromosome is:",len(seq)
print "No. of N in the chromosome are:", seq.count("N")
return seq

  #Method to replace the characters in sequence string
    def ReplaceSequence():
    seqList = list(sequence)        
    for index, item in enumerate(lstFirstCord):
      if seqList[index] != "N":
        seqList[index] = "N"
        newSequence = ''.join(seqList) 
    return newSequence

   #Method to write to genome file
   def WriteToGenomeFile(newSequence):
      try:
       with open("chr1.fa", 'rw+') as f:
        old_human_seq = f.read()      
        f.seek(0)                      
        f.write(newSequence)          
        print "Data modified in the genome file"
        print "Length of the new chromosome is:",len(newSequence)
        print "No. of N in the new chromosome are:", newSequence.count("N")
except:
    print 'File cannot be opened, wrong format you forgot something:', human_genome
    exit()


   sequence = ReadgenomeCharacter()

   print "Here is my mutaiton file data"

   data = np.genfromtxt("CLL608.txt",delimiter ="\t", dtype=None,skip_header=0)        #Reading the mutation file CLL608.txt

    #Storing the mutation file data in a dictionary
     subarray = ({'Chr1' : data[data[:,0] == 'chr1'],'Chr2': data[data[:,0] == 'chr2'],'Chr3': data[data[:,0] == 'chr3'],
    'Chr4': data[data[:,0] == 'chr4'], 'Chr5': data[data[:,0] == 'chr5'],'Chr6': data[data[:,0] == 'chr6'],
    'Chr7': data[data[:,0] == 'chr7'], 'Chr8': data[data[:,0] == 'chr8'],'Chr9': data[data[:,0] == 'chr9'],
    'Chr10': data[data[:,0] == 'chr10'] , 'Chr11': data[data[:,0] == 'chr11'],'Chr12': data[data[:,0] == 'chr12'],
    'Chr13': data[data[:,0] == 'chr13'], 'Chr14': data[data[:,0] == 'chr14'],'Chr15': data[data[:,0] == 'chr15'],
    'Chr16': data[data[:,0] == 'chr16'],'Chr17': data[data[:,0] == 'chr17'],'Chr18': data[data[:,0] == 'chr18'],
    'Chr19': data[data[:,0] == 'chr19'], 'Chr20': data[data[:,0] == 'chr20'],'Chr21': data[data[:,0] == 'chr21'],
     'Chr22': data[data[:,0] == 'chr22'], 'ChrX': data[data[:,0] == 'chrX']})

    #For each element in the dictionary, fetch the first cord and pass this value to the method to replace the character on first chord with N in the genome file
    for the_key, the_value in subarray.iteritems():
    cnt = len(the_value)
    for lst in the_value:
    chr_name = lst[0]
    first_cord = int(lst[1])
    second_cord = int(lst[2])
    lstFirstCord.append(first_cord)            

   #Call the method to replace the sequence
   newSeq = ReplaceSequence()
   print "length :", len(newSeq)
   #Call the method to write new data to genome file
   WriteToGenomeFile(newSeq)
   `
```

I am getting output like this

```
Enter UCSC fasta file of human genome:chr1.fa
chr1 
Length of the chromosome is: 249250622
No. of N in the chromosome are: 23970000
Here is my mutaiton file data
length : 249250622
File cannot be opened, wrong format you forgot something:
```

we can download the chr1.fa by typing the following command directly

```
rsync -avzP 
rsync://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/chromosomes/chr1.fa.gz .
```

Somehow I am not able to insert the N in the sequence and also not able to wirte the new sequence.
I will be glad if any valuable suggestion for improving the code :)

Comment: Clearly, the file `chr1.fa` is not present in the directory from which you ran your script. Did you uncompress it after you downloaded it?

Comment: yes i uncompressed it sorry i forgot to tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your life a bit easier, you may want to consider using Biopython to read in your fasta and do your converting.

Here's some documentation to get you started http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc16

Here is some starter code.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
handle = open("example.fasta", "rU")
output_handle = open("output.fasta", "w")
for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"):
     print record.seq
handle.close()
output_handle.close()
```

Comment: What does this code do other than open a file and print records? The OP wants to re-write a fasta file with mutation sites edited to N's...

Comment: It's to get him started, and it trimmed a lot of the tedious parsing out.

Comment: to be fair, looking at the OP's code, some help with the tedious parsing details might help ;)

Comment: The parsing is automatically handled for OP in my example starter code because SeqIO.parse will parse the fasta file for him and whatever he needs he just says record.(whatever he wants id,name,seq) as opposed to the way he is doing it now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might have some issues with locating the file directory and opening the file. That being said, your job is relatively easy one once you have the file data. You want to read in the fasta file, remove the header and convert it to a list, then simply replace the indices in your mutation file as "N" and recreate the fasta. Here are the steps:

```
from collections import defaultdict
chromosome = input("what chromosome are you editing? ")

# have all your file paths in order
mutations = path/to/mutations/file
fasta = path/to/fasta/file
newfile = path/to/new/file

# (1) get the mutations out of the mutations file into a list for each chrom
mutdict = defaultdict(list)
with open(mutations, "r") as f1:
    muts = f1.readlines()  # read all lines into list
    muts = [(x[0], int(x[1])) for x in muts]  # get the two columns you want

# (2) convert these to a dict
for (ch, pos) in muts:
    mutdict[ch].append(pos) 

# (3) get your fasta and convert it to a list
with open(fasta, "r") as f2:
    header = f2.readline()  # the first line is a header like ">chr1"
    bases  = f2.read().replace("\n", "")  # read all the bases and remove "\n"
bases = list(bases)  # turn the string into a list

# (4) now you loop through your mutations and change them to N in the fasta list
for mut in mutdict[chromosome]:
    bases[mut] = "N"

# (5) re-write the Fasta:
new_fasta = header
new_fasta = "\n".join("".join(bases[i:i + 50]) for i in xrange(len(bases)))
with open(newfile, "w") as out:
    out.write(new_fasta)
```